# the function to call all subClasses from superClass

Tags: swift, function

I guess this is an easy one but I've been searching for hours and still can't figure out what function do I call to do this.

so say I have one super class `country` and three subclasses like this

```
class country {
}

class USA : country {
}
class China : country {
}
class France : country {
}
var countrys : [country] = []
```

and I now want to push all subclasses into an array of country class

what do I call in append function??

```
countrys.append(contentsOf:  )
```

any hints are appreciated ! :D

Comment: A superclass doesn't know anything about its subclasses. You need to explicitly create an instance of each subclass and add it to the array

Answer (score 2):

What you would like to do is possible in Objective-C, using introspection, and in C++, using static code that gets run at the very start of the program. However, it is not possible in Swift.

While you can't get something that happens automatically, a manual approach will work.

Define your classes something like:

```
class Country {
    static var countries = [Country.Type]()
    static func addMe() { Country.countries.append(self) }
}

class USA : Country {
}
class China : Country {
}
class France : Country {
}
```

and in some initialisation code call:

```
USA.addMe()
France.addMe()
China.addMe()
```

then calling `print("Country.countries \(Country.countries)")` will give you:

```
Country.countries [Module.USA, Module.France, Module.China]
```

If this really needs to be done automatically, look into what you could do in Objective-C and have `Country` be a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: hey Gary thanks for answering! weird thing that Swift don't have such function to do it. I will try to read some more Objective-C documentation!

Answer (score 1):

No Objective C is required, desired, or needed.  In the most minimal way possible, you can create your `Country` arrays like this depending on whether they need to be read-only or read-write.

```
class Country {}

class USA: Country {}
class China: Country {}
class France: Country {}

var countries = [Country]()
countries.append(USA())
countries.append(China())
countries.append(France())

let moreCountries = [France(), China(), USA()]
```

However, creating individual subtypes for each possible country is a misuse of the type system at face value. Here is an alternate answer in a more idiomatic way. But this is a design question and is dependent on details not provided.

```
class Country {
   let name: String
}

var countries = [Country]()
countries.append(Country(name: "USA"))
countries.append(Country(name: "China"))
countries.append(Country(name: "France"))

let moreCountries = [Country(name: "France"), Country(name: "China"), Country(name: "USA"))

let usa = Country(name: "USA")
let china = Country(name: "China")
let france = Country(name: "France")
let evenMoreCountries = [china, france, usa]
```

Comment: thanks for answering and correcting my misspelled "countrys" ,  so if I have a lot of subclasses, I will have to append them to array one by one right ?

Comment: Yes, you will. All collections must be of the same type. In your example, the array of various subtypes uses the shared/common superclass type to make the array from. WARNING: No one would make individual subclasses for each country like you did. Be careful.